# How to gernerate *.hsh file for "contacts+message backup" app on windows phone 8

Tags: android, windows-phone-8, sms, backup

Microsoft hast released "contacts+message backup" for backup and restore contacts an messages. You can find the app here
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/contacts-message-backup/9nblgggz57gm

Now I want do gernerate my own xml file (in this case named as *.msg) to import my old sms from an android phone.

My problem is that I dont understand how to generate the .hsh content. I think it must be some hash value. But wich algo is used for this.

Here is an example value of the hash? file:
`VqWMrCwe4l0DS4uCGMyFS6LneXFSfWwz1KgVsMjJweqEQtsHgVElgWPT9jdE1TGH`

And this is the exportet message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ArrayOfMessage xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><Message><Recepients /><Body>Hallo! Tipps zur Verwendung Ihres neuen Handys erhalten Sie unter windowsphone.com/hello

Wenn Sie vorher ein anderes Handy genutzt haben, finden Sie unter windowsphone.com/switch Hilfe zum Übertragen von Inhalten von Ihrem alten Handy.

Diese Nachricht ist kostenlos.</Body><IsIncoming>true</IsIncoming><IsRead>true</IsRead><Attachments /><LocalTimestamp>130983145987125225</LocalTimestamp><Sender>Windows Phone</Sender></Message></ArrayOfMessage>
```

Any ideas how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution here: https://github.com/gpailler/Android2Wp_SMSConverter
There is also a pre installed version for copy paste.

Comment: You should not provide link only answers.  You should at least in this case supply a decent code example to outline the use of code you as suggesting be used.